# Equivalent to 'twiddle get "jboss.system:type=Server" Started'

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm searching for an equivalent to the command 'twiddle get "jboss.system:type=Server" Started' which was included in older jboss versions to get the server status.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/167959?tstart=0

For scripting usages (JBoss 7.1.1):

```
 - to check if JBoss server is started: ./jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="read-attribute server-state"

 - to check if application is started: ./jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="cd deployment,cd myapp.war, read-attribute status"
```